# (LOGIC) Determine whether a statement is correct using truth-tables

Tags: logic, truthtable

I'm trying to study for my midterm and I need help figuring out what to do for this problem. It says:

> Determine whether the following statement is correct, using any
> legitimate truth-table technique.
>
> ~A ∨ (B → C), E → (B & A), C → E  |= C ↔ A

I make a truth table for each statement but I don't how the main connective correlates with the other connectives in the other statements.

I think I have to make a joint table but I really don't know where to begin. If anyone can help me understand it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A,B,C |= D` *means* that if `A`,`B`,`C` are all true then `D` is true as well. But, this is exactly what the expression `(A & B & C) -> D` says. Thus `A,B,C |= D` is true if and only if `(A & B & C) -> D` is a tautology. In other words, the connective `->` captures the meaning of `|=`. For your problem, you can make a truth table for the compound expression

```
[(~A ∨ (B → C)) &  (E → (B & A)) & (C → E)] -> (C ↔ A)
```

and see if it is a tautology

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where did you get D from?

Comment: I was just stating a general principle of logic. The application your particular question followed.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you did what you did? I don't mean to be annoying but it's still not making much sense to me.